# Toggle css classes on element resize makes jittery

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, css-transitions

Am working on responsive layout but I can't figure out how to make a smooth transition on toggling a class with different styling.

I want to determine the size of an element on page load and add a class if the size is met. I am able to do that part and applied the same on resize event. But upon resizing the element is kinda jittery.

How do I prevent this from happening?

My code is simple like below:

```
 $(window).on('load',function (){

        let stats = $('.stats').width(),
            breakdown = $('.breakdown-item').width();

        if (stats < 860){
          $('.stats .upper').addClass('wrap');
        }else{
          $('.stats .upper').removeClass('wrap');
        }

        if (stats < 501) {
          $('.content-inner').addClass('wrap');
        }else{
          $('.content-inner').removeClass('wrap');
        }


        if (breakdown < 300) {
          $('.breakdown .breakdown-item').addClass('wrap');
        }else{
          $('.breakdown .breakdown-item').removeClass('wrap');
        }
      })

      $(window).on('resize',function() {
        var width = $('main .stats').width();

        if (width < 501) {
          $('.content-inner').addClass('wrap');
        }else{
          $('.content-inner').removeClass('wrap');
        }
        console.log(width);
      })
    })(jQuery)
```

https://codepen.io/leonardpbdigital/pen/KKwBzgy

Here's how it looks in action: https://share.getcloudapp.com/2Nur6jp2

Comment: Your CSS or (even better) some small demo would be very good!

Comment: And why don't you use a grid layout? Or media queries or flexbox (whatever suits you best)?

Comment: Exactly like Aaron said. That's CSS's job, not JS's.

Comment: please attach your html and css also. Its hard to grasp why it behaves like that with only js.

Comment: The reason this is happening is because you are watching the width of the two elements of which you are changing the width by adding the classes. So, when you add the 'wrap' class to the stats element, it now becomes bigger than 860px and therefore removes the class again.